# Tag Maintenance Summer 2019

Tags: discussion

We should do some tag maintenance, especially regarding printers to make them easier to read. Use an answer to propose a change, merge or split. Discussions for each change should go into the comments of each change.

Some things are easier than others:

- **Renaming** a tag can be done with mod tools.
- **Alias/Synonyms** are reasonably quick, often follow along renaming
- Some tags need **manual (separation)**.  Sifting through what is and what isn't this tag has to be done to separate the stuff. It can be noisy to the front site but has to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Laundry list:

### Open

- [e3d](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/438)
- [Creality](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/436)
- [Filled PLA](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/434)

### Done

- [Anet](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/431)
- [Flashforge](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/435)
- [Ultimaker](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/432)

  - [Ultimaker 1](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/437)
- [Cura](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/433)
- [Monoprice](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/445)

Comment: This is to make sure nothing is overlooked - it should be "top" as it is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

## Printers: Anet series

- [aneta2](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aneta2) -> [anet-a2](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anet-a2)
- [aneta6](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aneta6) -> [anet-a6](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anet-a6)
- [aneta8](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aneta8) -> [anet-a8](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anet-a8)

Type: **renaming**

Status: **Done** by [Greenonline](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4762/greenonline)

Comment: `anet-a2` definitely looks better than `aneta2`, so yes to this.

Comment: I'm in favor of this, this has been a thorn for a while. There are more printers with this problem

Comment: All done..! :-) Merged and `anetaX` is now a synonym of `anet-aX`

Answer (score 1):

## Manufacturer: [ultimaker](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker)

- Many questions in [ultimaker](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker) are not about the manufacturer but...

  - [cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cura), their Slicer; see [separate Item](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/8884)
  - [ultimaker-1](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-1) aka Ultimaker Original
  - [ultimaker-2](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-2) aka 2+
  - [ultimaker-3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-3) third product iteration
  - latest is the Ultimaker S5 (2019), no tag/questions yet

type: **manual**

Status: **Done**

2 questions remain: one about an unknown Ultimaker printer, one about an Ultimaker Filament (which I think should stay)

Comment: I've left a comment to see if the user can tell us which printer it is. The user still visits from time to time. We can't really tell from the date. Which models were available at the time of writing? It can't be #3, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimaker)

Comment: Just thought, what happens if it is an issue common to all Ultimaker printers? We tag all of the printers?

Comment: in those cases one could possibly tag the manufactuer, but up to now, I have only seen machine specific ones.

Comment: I've just noticed, in the question is says "ulmaker original +". So which one is that? Is that different from original, or 2, or 2+. Maybe it deserves it's own tag? Strangely, it is not listed in the [Wikipedia products section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimaker#Products), although google comes up with valid product pages, even on the [Ultimaker site](https://ultimaker.com/en/resources/manuals/ultimaker-3d-printers/ultimaker-original-plus). Confusing!

Comment: Original is 1, afaik, + is the upgrade... Possibly renaming turf? [tag:Ultimaker-1] to [tag:Ultimaker-original]?

Comment: Hmmm... I've just retagged it to ultimaker-1, and fixed the typos

Answer (score 1):

## Ultimaker Cura

This has some options:

1. Keep [cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cura)
2. Rename to [ultimaker-cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-cura), alias [cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cura) to it.
3. Keep [cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cura) *and* alias [ultimaker-cura](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-cura) to it.

Type: Variant 2, official name.

Status: **DONE** by Greenonline

Comment: Rename to the actual product name, so "ultimaker-cura". The slicer is called "Ultimaker Cura" not Cura, it changed from Cura to Ultimaker Cura a while ago. So the Cura tag should be renamed to "ultimaker-cura".

Comment: @0scar, that *does* make sense... but it also means we have to rename, or add new synonyms each time someone buys Cura...

Comment: An alias/synonym would make "type in Cura, get it set to Ultimaker-Cura" automatically. Often, renaming leaves behind an alias/synonym automagically.

Comment: All done. Merged, and `cura` is now a synonym of `ultimaker-cura`

Answer (score 1):

## Filled-PLA

Status: **TBD**

Type: **TBD: Alias/Synonym or Rename**

1. [filled-pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filled-pla) (current) reasonably gets the point across
2. [blended-pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blended-pla) would be a good synonym or alternate name
3. [modified-pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modified-pla) seems to be used synonymously but could be understood as a master-term for [pla+](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pla%2b) and [htpla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htpla) too.

Comment: filled-pla could (maybe) be confused with something being filled with PLA... unlikely, but blended is a lot less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

## Manufacturer: FlashForge

- Split up to their printers [flashforge-creator](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flashforge-creator) [flashforge-adventurer-3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flashforge-adventurer-3) [flashforge-finder](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flashforge-finder)
- added [flashprint](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flashprint)

Type: Manual

Status: **Done**. One [flashforge](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flashforge) question about a shared item remaining (and keeping the tag itself alive)

Answer (score 1):

## Printer manufacturer: Creality

Status: **Done**

Note that the tag for this manufacturer **does not exist**, printers are listed solely by the printer model type/name: [cr-10](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cr-10), [ender-3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender-3), [ender-4](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender-4) and [ender-5](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender-5).

In the light of FlashForge and Ultimaker, shouldn't the manufacturer be included (prefixed) in the tag?

Comment: technically, yes, but we can't keep a tag if we have no question with it. We'd need a question that has at least 2 printers targeted to tag creality or one about the company.

Comment: @Trish I cannot follow you, all 4 tags for printer models exist and could be prefixed with [tag:creality-...], I'm not in favor of adding the tag [tag:creality] unless there are questions for it. As a matter of fact it should already have been created and used for all listed models.

Comment: Oh, well, it is Creality-Ender-3, yes!

Comment: Hmmm... It would start to make the tags twice the length. On the other hand, having the makers name in the tag would avoid [this issue](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/canonicalizing-verbosifying-software-names), i.e. it ("Creality") would not need to be repeated in the question text itself.

Answer (score 1):

## Ultimaker 1

- Technically the [ultimaker-1](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-1) is named [ultimaker-original](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimaker-original)

Type: Rename

Status: **DONE** by [0scar](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users/5740/0scar)

Answer (score 1):

## Manufacturer: E3D

We have a lot of questions tagged [e3d](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d). Some concearn the [e3d-v6](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-v6), one the [e3d-titan-aero](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-titan-aero), I think I have seen at least one [e3d-volcano](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-volcano).

Should we split it? Should we weed out those that use [e3d](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d) but mean [all-metal-hotend](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/all-metal-hotend) instead, and make that tag?

Status: **TBD**

Answer (score 0):

## Manufacturer: Monoprice

Status: **Done**

This tag ([monprice](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monprice)) is used for tagging questions regarding various printer types while the tag itself is the manufacturer. In analogy to the other printer tags and types these should be re-tagged with the proper printer types.

The tag appears to be used 52 times, of which 27 times used this year. Printers that are tagged under the [monoprice](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monoprice) manufacturer tag are:

- Monoprice Architect
- Monoprice Select Mini (v1/v2)
- Monoprice Maker Select
- Monoprice Maker Select Plus
- Monoprice Maker Ultimate
- Monoprice Mini Delta
- Monoprice Dual Extrusion