# Tag Maintenance Winter 2019

Tags: discussion

Half a year passed since [Tag Maintenance Summer 2019](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/tag-maintenance-summer-2019). A lot was done, some wasn't, so cleanup and rinse and repeat: Let's do some tag maintenance, especially regarding printers to make them easier to read. Use an answer to propose a change, merge or split. Discussions for each change should go into the comments of each change.

Some things are easier than others:

- **Renaming** a tag can be done with mod tools.
- **Alias/Synonyms** are reasonably quick, often follow along renaming
- Some tags need **manual (separation)**.  Sifting through what is and what isn't this tag has to be done to separate the stuff. It can be noisy to the front site but has to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Laundry list:

### Open

- [Filled PLA](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/458/8884)
- [Repair vs. Maintenance](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/459/8884)

### Done

- [e3d](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/456/8884)
- [Monoprice](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/455/8884)
- [Creality](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/457/8884)
- [Prusa](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/460/8884)

Answer (score 1):

## Manufacturer: Monoprice

Status: **Done**

[Takeover from Summer 2019](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/8884)

This tag ([monprice](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monprice)) is used for tagging questions regarding various printer types while the tag itself is the manufacturer. In analogy to the other printer tags and types these should be re-tagged with the proper printer types.

The tag appears to be used 52 times, of which 27 times used this year. Printers that are tagged under the [monoprice](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monoprice) manufacturer tag are:

- Monoprice Maker Architect
- Monoprice Select Mini (v1/v2)
- Monoprice Maker Select
- Monoprice Maker Select Plus
- Monoprice Maker Ultimate
- Monoprice Mini Delta
- Monoprice Dual Extrusion

*Note the "MP" is dropped from certain names, this should be related to **M**ono**P**rice.*

Answer (score 1):

## Printer manufacturer: Creality

Status: **Done**

[Takeover from Summer 2019](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/436/8884)

Note that the tag for this manufacturer **does not exist**, printers are listed solely by the printer model type/name: [cr-10](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cr-10), [ender-3](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender-3), [ender-4](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender-4) and [ender-5](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ender-5).

In the light of FlashForge and Ultimaker, shouldn't the manufacturer be included (prefixed) in the tag?

Comment: Hmmm... It would start to make the tags twice the length. On the other hand, having the makers name in the tag would avoid [this issue](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/canonicalizing-verbosifying-software-names), i.e. it ("Creality") would not need to be repeated in the question text itself. – Greenonline♦ Sep 2 at 9:12

Comment: I cannot follow you, all 4 tags for printer models exist and could be prefixed with creality-..., I'm not in favor of adding the tag creality unless there are questions for it. As a matter of fact, it should already have been created and used for all listed models. – 0scar♦ Aug 31 at 20:54

Answer (score 1):

## Prusa

Status:**Done**

Type: Re-tag

In light of correcting tags to the official names [prusa](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prusa) should be [prusa-research](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prusa-research)

Answer (score 0):

## Manufacturer: E3D

Status: **Done**/split up

[Takeover from Summer 2019](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/438/8884)

We have a lot of questions tagged [e3d](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d). Some concearn the [e3d-v6](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-v6), one the [e3d-titan-aero](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-titan-aero), I think I have seen at least one [e3d-volcano](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-volcano). As of today (updated), there's a pair of [e3d-hemera](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-hemera)/(formerly: [e3d-hemes](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-hemes)) and a single [e3d-v5](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-v5) on a very old question.

Should we split it? Should we weed out those that use [e3d](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d) but mean [all-metal-hotend](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/all-metal-hotend) instead, and make that tag?

- It has been split.

Answer (score 0):

## Filled-PLA

Status: **TBD**

Type: **TBD: Alias/Synonym or Rename**

[Takeover from Summer 2019](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/434/8884)

1. [filled-pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filled-pla) (current) reasonably gets the point across
2. [blended-pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blended-pla) would be a good synonym or alternate name
3. [modified-pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modified-pla) seems to be used synonymously but could be understood as a master-term for [pla+](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pla%2b) and [htpla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htpla) too.

Comment: filled-pla could (maybe) be confused with something being filled with PLA... unlikely, but blended is a lot less ambiguous. – Greenonline♦ Aug 31 at 9:37

Answer (score 0):

## Repair vs. Maintenance

Status: **TBD**

We have both a [repair](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repair) and a [maintenance](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag with 10 and 25 Questions respectively. Repair is described as:

> Use this tag to indicate the actions or activities to undertake to fix an item or a process.

while Maintenance is

> Questions about general maintenance and upkeep of printers.

I would like to redraw the distinguishing line, which is rather blurry:

- Maintenance can be replacing worn parts, which also could be seen as repair if it brings a machine back to specs.
- some maintenance tagged questions are also [troubleshooting](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting), which means they could equally well be tagged repair
- other maintenance tagged questions are tagged with [replacement-parts](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replacement-parts), which would imply a repair of the first type happening as part of routine maintenance (and could arguable count as a repair)

As those tags are rather similar, we need to find a solution:

1. Redraw the line and distinguish better, maybe recategorize parts.

   - maybe [model-repair](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-repair) vs. [printer-maintenance](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printer-maintenance)?
2. Merge the tags into one or the other (maintenance is more inclusive), alias one to the other?
3. Keep as it is?
4. Other?

Comment: I would disagree with a merge, mainly because while they can related, they are still distinctly different. I mean, on Mech we differentiate between the two even in the title of our Stack. I do agree there can be a gray area between the two where they can overlap. Personally, I think if something falls into the gray realm, maybe both tags should be used. Just thinking out loud, though.